# I/P issue testing HTTP service on local computer

Tags: android, visual-studio-2010, http, rest

My development computer is assigned a local I/P of 192.168.2.7 on my LAN.

If I enter `http://localhost` into a browser I get my computer's IIS screen as expected (running Win7).

If I enter `http://192.168.2.7` into a browser I get my computer's IIS screen as expected.

I have an HTTP service listening on port 50421.(Visual Studio)

If I enter `http://localhost:50421` into a browser I get the proper response from my HTTP service

if I enter `http://192.168.2.7:50421` into a browser both firefox and I.E. say they cannot connect.

Why is this?  Why can't I use my machine's IP address in my testing?  My computer's I/P works but not when used in conjunction with a port.  I've also tried it from other machines on my LAN getting the same result.

The practical reason why I need to do this is because I'm testing client calls from both the Windows Phone 7, and Android AVD emulators where I can't use "localhost" I must use my machine's IP.  If I can't figure out a way to do this, I can't debug my POST services.

BTW, the service runs fine when deployed to my production web server but I can't step through the code there.

Any Idea what could be wrong?

Thanks, Gary

Comment: Your Visual Studio process is only listening on 127.0.0.1:50421 and not your LAN IP. You need to let the service listen to the IP:s you want to be able to connect to.

Answer (score 0):

Some router brands won't let you do that, try accessing from the WAN with your global IP and setup port forwarding.